# How can i make this shape with CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #FFB4B4;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><h1>Lorem Ipsum nkdsdkjdks diosudisuidus</h1><p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. </p><button>test</button></div>
```

How can i make this Shape with only CSS without using extra plugin or javascript or anything.
It should work with all major Browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, IE.

Note: I do not wanna use Shape Image for it.

[image: Shape with CSS only]

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: added some code, but i do not know how to make this shape, that is why asked here.

Comment: This will help you get understand. HTML code  `<body><div></div></body>` CSS code `body {margin:0;}body {height: 100vh;background: linear-gradient(120deg, pink 65%, white 25%)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite not being the best way to ask a question I suppose this is what you want.

HTML

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

CSS

```
.shape {
  width: 80px;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
}
```

This will create the shape you want but you can easily get to this result if you do a quick search for shapes in css